# Cannot read property 'error' of undefined. What's the problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, api

My REST API reasons this: `{"error":"Auth failed. User does not exist"}`.
I try save this error to my state using setState in React, but I have a this error: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined. What's the problem?

```
export const login = user =>
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:3000/api/users/login', {
      login: user.login,
      password: user.password,
    })
    .then(res => {
      localStorage.setItem('userToken', res.data.token);
      return res.data.token;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Function in React.js:

```
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      login: this.state.login,
      password: this.state.password,
    };

    login(user).then(res => {
      if (!res.error) { // <- this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
        this.props.history.push(`/dashboard`);
      } else {
        this.setState({ error: res.error });
      }
    });
  }
```

This is my backend code:

```
    // Login Action
...
              return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Auth successful',
                token,
              });
            }
            res
              .status(400)
              .json({ error: 'Auth failed. The password is incorrect.' });
          } else {
            res.status(400).json({ error: 'Auth failed. User does not exist' });
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).json({ error: err });
        });
    };
```

Comment: Use console.log(res) to see what is returned actually from backend as response, then you can tell the structure of response and to see if error is maybe structured as res.data.error or something else. This way in res object property error doesn't exist.

Comment: My first guess would be that if you have an error, you are not returning anything in the catch block ? So maybe add `return error` in your catch block will solve it

EDIT : `cannot read property of undefined` means that your `res` is undefined, so thath might be the reason why you have to return something from the catch block

Comment: Hi, the method login is in same file as the one in React.js?
The easiest would be to setState directly when you catch the error:    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

Comment: @RomainLeQllc I edited my post and add controller code.

Comment: I meant the catch block in your `login` function, where you have a `console.log(err)`. Does it log anything when you go into the catch case ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
login(user).then(() => this.props.history.push(`/dashboard`))
.catch(error=>this.setState({ error })
```

But maybe there is another problem, you cannot normally push to state the way you do for immutability concern. I guess you know, but I post in case:

```
this.setState({ history: [...this.state.history, `/dashboard`] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
export const login = user =>
axios
.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users/login', {
  login: user.login,
  password: user.password,
})
.then(res => {
  localStorage.setItem('userToken', res.data.token);
})
.then(() => return localStorage.getItem('userToken');)
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: still showing undefined error? have you tried in this way I just edited?

Answer (score 0):

since your backend is returning a response with 400 status code, you have to handle that in the catch block of your login function. right now you are writing the error into the console and not returning anything, that is why your login response is undefined in your React code and you are getting that error.
to fix this, change the catch block of your login function so it looks something like this

```
 .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return {error:err};
});
```